# ImageView scale type not working in list activity

Tags: android, listview, scale, imageview, expandablelistview

I have used ImageView's before and understand the different scale types that can be set... However I am having an incredibly difficult time trying to get an ImageView to scale properly in the row of a ListActivity or an ExpandableListActivity.

I have tried setting the android:scaleType property to every single value but the image never scales down.  I have set the min and max sizes as well and they don't seem to have any effect.  I have done both of these things in both the XMl and in code to no avail...

Does anyone have any ideas or perhaps a workaround?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the XML for the group rows in an ExpandableListView

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="6dip"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_selection_icon_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:minWidth="10dp"
    android:minHeight="10dp"
    android:maxWidth="10dp"
    android:maxHeight="10dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
/>

<!--  App Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_app_name_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_selection_icon_id"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/item_selection_icon_id"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    android:textSize="24sp"
/>

<!-- Package Information -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_app_pkg_name_id"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_app_name_id"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_selection_icon_id"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textSize="12sp"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No ideas whatsoever?  The problem is that I am displaying icons from any app installed on the device.  Not all of the icons are the same size and I want to scale them to be the same size in my list...

Comment: Off the top of my head: Have you tried setting layout_width/height to `10dp`, instead of `wrap_content`?

Comment: That works!  I can't believe that I didn't think to do that... I wonder though, what is the difference exactly between layout_width/height and normal width/height...

Comment: I was exactly in the same situation! thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to Roman, this problem has been solved!  I removed the min and max width and height lines and changed the android:layout_width/height attributes to the size I wanted and everything is now working out just fine.